# Better way to compare the list of records in apex?

Tags: apex

```
public static void checkOpportunityAccountype(Id opportunityId){
                Set<String> supportedAccountTypeIds = new Set<String>{
    '2XXX','2XXX','2XXX','2XXX','2XXX','2XXX','2XXX','2XXX','2XXX','2XXX','2XXX','2XXX','2XXX','2XXX','2XXX','2XXX'

                };
                List<Opportunity> oppRecord = new List<Opportunity>();   
                try {
                    oppRecord = [Select Id,Account.AccountType__c from Opportunity Where Id =: opportunityId];
                    if(!oppRecord.isEmpty()){
                        if(supportedAccountTypeIds.contains(oppRecord[0].Account.AccountType__c)){
                            return;    
                        } else {
                            throw new CustomException(Label.X, 1);
                        }
                    }
                } catch(CustomException ce) {
                    throw new AuraHandledException(
                            JSON.serialize(ce)
                    );
                }
                return;
            }
```

I have like 30 account types for which I have to see if the selected opportunities account's account type is included in the the 30 types. I have used a set to contain but I think this looks clumsy and if in the future if I wanted to more than I would have to add them in here where it might look more clumsy. Is there any other better way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom Metadata / Custom Setting makes it easier to manage.

For a short example based on custom metadata,

1. Create Custom Metadata Type (The name in the example is 'SampleMetadata')
2. Create Custom Text Field (The Name in the example is 'AccountType__c')
3. Create Record (The Name in the example is 'Account')

   - Enter the valid type in the Account Type field, separated by ','.

**Example**

public class Check {

```
public static Set<String> accountTypes;

static {
     SampleMetadata__mdt meta = [SELECT Id,AccountType__c 
                                    FROM SampleMetadata__mdt 
                                  WHERE DeveloperName ='Account' LIMIT 1];

     accountTypes = new Set<String>();

     List<String> tokenizedValue = meta.AccountType__c.split(',');
     for( String value : tokenizedValue ){
         accountTypes.add(value);
     }
}


    public static void checkOpportunityAccountype(Id opportunityId){

        List<Opportunity> oppRecord = new List<Opportunity>();   
        try {
            oppRecord = [Select Id,Account.AccountType__c from Opportunity Where Id =: opportunityId];
            if(!oppRecord.isEmpty()){
                if(accountTypes.contains(oppRecord[0].Account.AccountType__c)){
                    return;    
                } else {
                    throw new CustomException(Label.X, 1);
                }
            }
        } catch(CustomException ce) {
            throw new AuraHandledException(
                    JSON.serialize(ce)
            );
        }
        return;
      }
}
```

}